# Server 19.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 defaults to root?

Tags: server, permissions, sudo, 19.10, raspberrypi

I've successfully installed Server 19.10, then got a desktop (Lubuntu) going on a single Raspberry Pi 4 (4gb). I went with the 32-bit version, having heard the 64-bit is not very stable. (Please contradict me if not so.) Some weirdness came with the desktop (e.g., doesn't show network icon in panel), but basically functional. My problem is the install created a passworded account named `ubuntu`, but this appears to be root. I didn't notice that when doing `sudo apt-get install`, I wasn't being prompted for the password, i.e., this must be root, correct? I blithely installed many packages, moved over files before I noticed this, BTW. So, I assume I really should create a "normal" Ubuntu account with `sudo` privileges? Then I should move everything in this original `/home/ubuntu` user/group-wise over to the normal account? The main reason I'm worried about this is I am a teacher and I want to set up many RPi4's, and they can't all be user `ubuntu` with automatic root privileges. What can I do at this point?

Comment: You installed Ubuntu 19.10?  and not Ubuntu 19.10.1? https://ubuntu.com/blog/updated-images-of-ubuntu-for-the-raspberry-pi-2-3-and-4  (a number of issues in 19.10 were fixed with the 19.10.1 release)  *Note: I'm no expert on pi's, but I read/believe it fixed the issues with arm64 especially*

Comment: `ubuntu-19.10.1-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz`

Answer (score 0):

Login to the admin users of the operating system

The default admin username is:             **pi**

and the password for the admin user is:   **raspberry**

Then change the default root password

```
      sudo passwd root
```

Enter the password for root

Now try to login root user

```
          sudo root
```

Enter the password for the root

(or)

```
         sudo su
```

Enter the password for the pi.